# Instance for existential wrapper with a variable in contravariant position

Tags: haskell, typeclass, existential-type

I have the following definition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

module Test
where

class Named a where
  name :: a -> String

data Wrap = forall a . (Named a, Read a) => Wrap (a -> IO ())
```

I want to write `Named` instance for `Wrap`. The next doesn't work:

```
instance Named Wrap where
  name (Wrap named) =
    let a = undefined
        _ = named a
    in name a
```

The error:

```
Could not deduce (Named a0) arising from a use of ‘name’
from the context (Named a, Read a)
```

But the following works:

```
instance Named Wrap where
  name (Wrap named) =
    let a = read undefined
        _ = named a
    in name a
```

The only difference I see is that `a` is in covariant position in `read`, but in contravariant possition in `name`. Why doesn't the first instance declaration work?

Comment: Are you trying to give names to types or to values? In any case, `name (Wrap named)` cannot depend on anything and must be a constant.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it is constant, so `undefined` is fine for me. The example is pretty silly, the real use case if more useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first instance doesn't work because it doesn't trigger the monomorphism restriction, so `a` gets a polymorphic type which is instantiated *differently* in `named a` and `name a`. On the other hand, when writing `a = read undefined`, we find that `a` has a typeclass-restricted type, so the monomorphism restriction kicks in and we must choose a specific type for `a`; since `named a` uniquely identifies this type, that type is chosen and it is not instantiated at a different type in `name a`.

You can cause the `read` version to fail by turning on `NoMonomorphismRestriction` to verify that this is the correct explanation.

You can fix the problem by using a lambda instead of a let, as in:

```
instance Named Wrap where
    name (Wrap named) = (\a -> (\_ -> name a) (named a)) undefined
```

(Generally, `let x = e in e'` is the same as `(\x -> e') e`, provided `x` is monomorphic and not recursive, and I have performed this rewrite twice here.)

However, I would suggest a more serious reworking of your approach to avoid `undefined` entirely, if possible. The standard trick for this is:

```
class Named a where
    name :: proxy a -> String

proxyForFun :: (a -> IO ()) -> Proxy a
proxyForFun _ = Proxy

instance Named Wrap where
    name (Wrap named) = name (proxyForFun named)
```

However, the type of `name` is quite restrictive: it is no longer possible to write instances in which `name` inspects its argument, so if that was a feature you needed this approach will not work.